# Force FireFox to launch on an URL, with no other tabs

Tags: firefox, command-line

I can pass a -url="..." parameter to launch FF for a URL, but I want to launch it with just that URL open, nothing else... I'm testing a browser plugin so if other pages are automatically opened from a previous session, this is pretty annoying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a second firefox profile (start using `-profilemanager`) and select that profile (`-P profilename`) for your browser plugin testing ([disable session restore](http://webtoolsandtips.com/firefox/firefox-restore-session/) for that profile).